# React: How to solve Source has 1 element(s) but target allows only 0?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to fetch data from an API and display them, but when I try to do the spread operator on the data array, I get error. Could someone please help with this?

This is the error I'm getting:

> Argument of type '(currentArrayList: []) => [any]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<[]>'.   Type '(currentArrayList:
> []) => [any]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: []) => []'.
> Type '[any]' is not assignable to type '[]'.
> Source has 1 element(s) but target allows only 0.  TS2345

This is the code:

```
const API_URL = 'https:pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon';

interface Props {
  pokemonItem: PokemonItem[];
  children: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[];
} 


export const PokemonContainer: React.FC = (props) => {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = React.useState([]);
  const [loadItems, setLoadItems] = React.useState(API_URL);

  const getPokemons = async () => {
    const response: any = await fetch(loadItems);
    const data = await response.json();

    setLoadItems(data.next);
    setPokemon(response.data.results[0].name);

    console.log(response.data.results);

    const getEachPokemon = (result: any) => {
      result.forEach(async (element: any) => {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https:pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${element.name}`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setPokemon((currentArrayList) => [...currentArrayList, data]);
      });
    };

    getEachPokemon(data.results);
    await console.log(pokemon);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getPokemons();
  }, []);
```

**Update**:

```
export interface PokemonItem {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    height: string;
    weight: string;
    abilities: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because `const [pokemon, setPokemon] = React.useState([]);` is not typed. If you add a type to the useState itll stop complaining, e.g:
`React.useState<any[]>([])`.

However, I would recommend not using any and actually creating a type that reflects what a pokemon would look like. I would also recommend not using any in the other places of your code and try to use types as much as possible :)

Comment: thanks. I have actually created an Interface as Type, but I wasn't sure about it. Now I get a related error. "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'results')"

Comment: Hmm yeah I would have to see how the types look and the code thats reading results to try and help debug

Comment: It looks like you're saying ` setPokemon(response.data.results[0].name);` but you shuold be doing ` setPokemon(data.results[0].name);` since you're turning the response into json and storing it in the `data` variable. So I would just console.log(data) and then start playing around with that!

Comment: Great. probably one last thing I get error is with the spread operator part, which say: " Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: ...) If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead".         setPokemon((currentArrayList) => [...currentArrayList, data]);

Comment: With the current data type that I need, any suggestion on what types I could use instead of 'any' in the getEachpokemon function?

Comment: For the error part, maybe you're not returning the right thing when mapping over `pokemon`. For the typing part, it is hard to type stuff that comes back from an external api since it can change at any moment, but if you really want you could look at the current structure and build a type interface based off it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238260/discussion-between-meeoh-and-user14765634).